# How to mount clipless pedals on a tandem?

Tags: shimano, pedals, tandems, pedals-clipless

My wife and I have recently purchased a vintage tandem, and are willing to switch to Shimano SPD pedals (M520).

The problem is that there are 3 "chainring" sides on a tandem, 2 of which are located on the left side of the bike. So basically I don't see any way to fit the pedals in the correct position, except for the stoker right side, because the threads will be the wrong way round.

How do I fit normal pedals onto tandem cranks?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The left pedals go on the left side and the right pedals go on the right.

Comment: On a regular bike, there is a dedicated left pedal and a dedicated right pedal. They have opposite threading. The crankshaft arm (on the right) can only be mounted with the right pedal. Problem is that on the tandem, there are 2 crankshafts located on the left side. If I mount my "right" pedal on the left side, the front and rear of the pedal will be reversed. Note that I am talking of SPD which have a front and a rear, and cannot be used if reversed

Comment: And it's the same on a tandem.  The left pedals go on the left side, the right pedals go on the right side.

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you ride a tandem ? Do you have clipless pedals on it ?

Comment: Unless you have a real oddball bike, the crank arms are reasonably standard, even though there are chainrings on both sides of the stoker's crank.  The difference between left and right pedals is the thread of the shaft -- pedals on the right have a right-hand (normal) thread, while pedals on the left have a left-hand (backwards) thread.

Comment: Page 15: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/C1QACKANHcS.pdf

Comment: I will note that, if the bike has 3-piece cranks, there's a vague possibility that, in it's prior life, the original crank arms failed and the person making repairs reached into their spare parts pile and substituted "normal" crank arms, putting right arms on the left side, etc.  Then they would have installed pedals on the "wrong" sides to match.  If this is the case your best option is to replace the crank arms with "proper" ones, though finding the correct arms could be difficult.

Comment: @DanielRHicks ...and the easy way to check would be to pay careful attention to whether the current pedals remove in the expected way (be that clockwise or anticlockwise)

Comment: If by chance or rather poor repair one left arm has been replaced by a right arm it is best in the interest of safety to put a proper left crank-arn back instead as the pedal may come off in a worst case scenario.

Comment: Aside - the captain and stoker can have different styles of pedal according to rider prefence.

Answer (score 15):

Tandem cranks are special. The pedal thread directions on each arm are oriented correctly to prevent loosening from precession, as on any other bike. You just need two sets of normal pedals.

If somehow non-tandem cranks have been installed such that either of the left cranks are right-threaded or the right captain crank is left-threaded, that situation is not acceptable and threadlockers will not make it so given the danger level of the crash that could result. Either get tandem cranks or get the offending crank(s) helicoiled to have proper thread orientation to resist loosening.

Comment: Tandem cranks are also fun for making left-side drive bikes.

Comment: It will be easy to check whether the pedals are correctly threaded by taking them off. The right one turns anti-clockwise while the left one turns clockwise.

Comment: Are tandem front-cranks and track bike left-side cranks essentially the same ?

Comment: @Criggie Nope, captain cranks have a LH thread on the left, geared arm and a RH thread on the right arm (which looks like a left arm from a normal set in every other way.)

Comment: Yeah so that sounds exactly the same as those track bikes where the chain is on the left side of the bike.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that there were special tandem cranks (for the left side). Clearly, our tandem has regular cranks on the left side, meaning only right pedals will fit. I guess the previous pedals have been mounted with blue loctite or so since it was quite hard to unscrew. Thank you guys for your comments. I will most likely keep the "regular" cranks on the left side, and either swap the axles of my Left/right pedals, or purchase a pair of symetric pedals like Crankbrothers.

Comment: @Criggie: Regarding threading, yes, probably the way you are thinking. There are a handful of drivechain configurations for tandems, so there isn't a single crank style necessarily, but I imagine you are thinking of a left-side spider and right side "bare" crank arm. That's what I was referring to in my comment.

Comment: @magicloic In that case, you could have the three wrong-threaded arms helicoiled so that they're properly threaded. That would be far safer. I'm personally down on the idea that blue loctite is enough here.

Comment: Also note the right captain's crank is going to be wrong too if it's indeed a normal left crank that's been put there.

Comment: It looks like a completely f...ed-up, home-made Franken-tandem drive system with irregular cranks and threading. In the interest of riders' safety I would have it checked by a competent cycle mechanic and have the crank/pedal issues addressed. Otherwise I'd abstain from riding it.

Comment: @Criggie : Left-side driven track bikes are purpose-built and use cranks that have been specially made with correctly threaded pedal threading, lefty-lefty, righty-righty. Anything else is certainly illegal by UCI-rules out of safety concerns.